# Do i have access to source code to modify in IBM MobileFirst MFP Admin Console?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

> Can i make some changes in MFP Admin console like changing the user >permissions, roles and so on ..., using IBM MobileFirst v7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source for the console is available in the admin .war file you have deployed to your application server. However note that this operation is not supported by IBM. If you encounter any errors, you're on your own.